# quero fazer compilar o java mas não consigo

Tags: java

já instalei a JDK, JRE, coloquei td q tinha q colocar no path.
o javac tá funcionado mas quando dou o comando "java HelloWorld" é exibido o seguinte erro "Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal HelloWorld.class".

```
  package java;

  public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

tá aí o programa .

[image: pasta onde está o arquivo]

Comment: Como você está executando os comandos?

Comment: primeiro dei o javac HelloWorld.java,aí gerou o HelloWorld.class,aí eu dou java HelloWorld e exibe o erro

Comment: ta executando do terminal/cmd direto ou de uma IDE?

Comment: pelo prompt de comando

Answer (score 1):

Aqui funcionou normalmente ao remover a informação de package:

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu tirei mesmo assim não pegou.

Comment: eu vou mudar o pacote

Comment: @libnarodrigues não pode ter informacao de pacote, remova do codigo, salve-o, recompile-o, execute-o. Se for dessa forma, nao vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: tá retornando o mesmo erro,deixa pra lá.

Comment: @libnarodrigues os comandos java e javac executados sozinho retornam alguma coisa?

Comment: sim aparecem vários coisas.tipo Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and

Comment: C:\Users\adnas\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\projetos web\java>java
Uso: java [-options] class [args...]
           (para executar uma classe)
   ou  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (para executar um arquivo jar)
em que as opções incluem:
    -d32          usar um modelo de dados de 32 bits, se estiver disponível